# Spring-jpa-data: more than one DataSource and one single Spring config

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use Crud Repository from Spring-jpa-data:

My config with data access beans looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan (basePackages = {"com.comp.olme"})
@PropertySource("classpath:OlmeSmb-${env}.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.comp.olme", entityManagerFactoryRef ="emGapSort", transactionManagerRef = "txManagerGapSort")
@EnableScheduling
public class OlmeSmbConfig {

   @Bean
    public BasicDataSource olmeDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource olmeDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        ...
        return olmeDataSource;
    }



    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource gapSortDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource gapSortDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
      ...
        return gapSortDataSource;
    }



    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emFactoryOLME(@Qualifier("olmeDataSource") BasicDataSource olmeDataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localConnectionFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      ...
        return localConnectionFactoryBean;
    }



    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emFactoryGapSort(@Qualifier("gapSortDataSource") BasicDataSource gapSortDataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localConnectionFactoryBeanGapSort = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
     ...
        return localConnectionFactoryBeanGapSort;
    }


    @Bean
    public EntityManager emOLME(@Qualifier("emFactoryOLME") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager emGapSort(@Qualifier("emFactoryGapSort") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }



    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager txManagerOLME(@Qualifier("emFactoryOLME") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryOLME) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManagerOLME = new JpaTransactionManager();
        ...
        return txManagerOLME;
    }


    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager txManagerGapSort(@Qualifier("emFactoryGapSort") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryGapSort) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManagerGapSort = new JpaTransactionManager();
      ....
        return txManagerGapSort;
    }

}
```

So, as you can see, i have two datasources, two EntityManagerFactories, two TransactionManagers and others...

But i pass only one EntityManagerFactory into `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation (`entityManagerFactoryRef ="emGapSort"`).

The question is: how two use more than one DataSources (entityManagerFactory) with Spring-jpa-data?

I read one example where splitting config described as a solution, but i would like to use one single Spring Config. Is it possibe?
Thank you.

Comment: it is not possible. You have to split to 2 Java config. You will get compile error when try to define 2 @EnableJpaRepositories within a config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From spring boot - [#5401](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5401)

> After a careful consideration we've decided not to implement this. That annotation proposal of yours is a mix of configuration key prefix, bean prefix and other bean-related settings. While it sounds appealing on paper, it would be quite hard to implement and probably even harder to keep it consistent with user's customizations.

So, you may try put it on two `@Configuration` classes (one `@EnableJpaRepositories` per `@Configuration`).